# How to display a php variable in input checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I made a small user database with some checkboxes in a html input form.
In there I have some basic infos about the users like value 1 and 2 (among others) and some checkboxes as well (here you see one). Default is always 0, but when I click the checkbox its changes to 1.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Value 1" value="<?php echo set_value('value1'); ?>" name="value1" size="6"/>
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="spec1"/><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="spec1"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Value 2" value="<?php echo set_value('value2'); ?>" name="value2" size="6"/>
```

Now I  would like to have a form in which I can see all these informations later on and edit it if necessary. But the checkbox I can't display properly. It is always empty. So I had to change it to a textbox. So I can see whether that specific values are 0 or 1.

```
<input type="text" name="Value 1" value="<?php echo $value1; ?>">
<input type="text" name="spec1" value="<?php echo $spec1; ?>">
<input type="text" name="Value 2" value="<?php echo $value2; ?>">
```

Is it possible somehow to show the values in a checkbox again, so I can change the type of the second line to "checkbox" again instead of "text"? Means can I display a value 1 as a checked checkbox and 0 as an empty checkbox?

Comment: to check your checkbox use the attribute 'checked' : `<input type="checkbox" name="Value 1" checked>`

Comment: to expand a bit: `<input type='checkbox' name='someName' <?php if ($someValue==1) echo 'checked="checked"'>`. this will set the checked attribute if your value matches a condition. Hope that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this code , you can use checkbox and check value is set and you need to show user so you checkbox level then you can use

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Value 1" value="<?php echo $value1; ?>"><?php echo $value1; ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="spec1" value="<?php echo $spec1; ?>"> <?php echo $spec1; ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="Value 2" value="<?php echo $value2; ?>"> <?php echo $value2; ?>
```

for demo test check this code also

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Value 1" value="1">Test1
<input type="checkbox" name="spec1" value="2"> Test2
<input type="checkbox" name="Value 2" value="3"> Test3
```

and if you want to checkbox checked then use also this

```
<?php
 $value1 = 1;
 $spec1 = 2;
 $value2 = 3;

 $compare_value = 3;
 ?>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Value 1" value="1" <?php if($value1 ==$compare_value) { echo 'checked';}?>>Test1
 <input type="checkbox" name="spec1" value="2" <?php if($spec1 ==$compare_value) { echo 'checked';}?>> Test2
 <input type="checkbox" name="Value 2" value="3" <?php if($value2 ==$compare_value) { echo 'checked';}?>> Test3
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes aren't checked or not by their value attribute. They have a checked attribute:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

So in your example:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="..." <?php if($value1) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> >
```

Answer (score 0):

What checks a checkbox is the `checked` attribute not `value`

You can add that attribute depending on the value you are retrieving from your database like so:

```
<?php if($value == 1): ?>
   <?php echo '<input type="checkbox" checked name="spec1"/>' ?>
<?php else: ?>
   <?php echo '<input type="checkbox" name="spec1"/>' ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

or for short

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php if(value == 1) echo 'checked'; ?> name="spec1"/>
```

Comment: THANKS to all of you guys!!!! :))) thats why i never found a solution online, because i was looking from a wrong perspective. thanks a lot, now it works fine!!!